# Externalize YML file outside WAR in Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-data

Externalizing `application-DEV.yml` file in Spring Boot application but it is not working. Spring boot version 2.6.6 . Below property defined in `application.yml`

```yaml
spring:
    config:
      import:
      - optional:file:/Users/Public/IN/application-DEV.yml
```

results in

```java
Error: Could not resolve placeholder 'daon.service.keystorePath' in value "${daon.service.keystorePath}"
```

Above key `daon.service.keystorePath` is defined in `application-DEV.yml` but while running application `spring.config.import` is not working. Expect: `spring.config.import` should work.

Comment: Is `/Users/Public` an actual path? `/Users` should be in the root of your system. If you aren't on windows the casing also matters.

Comment: I am using Window and path is correct

Comment: If you are using Windows the path isn't correct as it should include the drive then. I suspect it will crash with this file path as soon as you remove the `optional:` part.

Comment: I use same configuration in my other microservice and its working there ..... i doubt do i missing any dependency

Comment: If you would be missing a dependency it wouldn't do anything. Humor me and remove the optional and see what happens. As stated I bet it breaks.